# Crontab and PHP script

Tags: php, cron

I'm currently experiencing an issue that I just can't find it being solved online. I have tried two different Operating systems, and both have the same difficulty. One is Ubuntu, the other os OSx.

now the issue is, for this example, running a cron every minute to hit a .php file which in turn increments the count of a value found in a .txt file by 1.

At the beginning of the .php file I have:

#!/usr/bin/php

I have also tried adding the quiet tag at the end. Which didn't result in the cron working.

The cron command is as follows:

- - - - - php /var/www/cron/index.php >/dev/null 2>&1

The output found inthe syslog under CRON is:

(user) CMD (php /var/www/cron/index.php >/dev/null 2>&1)

With no errors. 
If I run that command as it is given. The count in the .txt is incremented by 1. But there is nothing  to show why the cron doesn't allow this to happen.

Sorry for the essay. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that `/var/www/cron/index.php` is normal PHP file, try: `* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/cron/index.php > /var/www/cron/index_output.txt` and let me know if you really have any output in `index_output.txt`. For test, you can put `<?php echo 'test ';` in `index.php` to see if it works. Also create `index_output.txt` first and make it 0777 for example, so we can be sure it's not permissions matter.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply Michael. I tested your suggestion. index_output.txt did infact increment by 1 at the turn of every minute. However the initial file text.txt stayed the same.

Also if I run the php file either via browser or just php /var/www/cron/index.php the text.txt file is incremented.

Comment: This has made me seem silly. After seeing related questions. One had missed my attention. I browsed through it and found a comment that stated files linked in a cron'ed file is required to be absolute paths. Implementing this resolved the issue! Thanks for the suggestions though Michal Prajsnar.

Comment: Because I am a new poster. I am unable to answer the question myself.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your `index.php` code or just the part of it where `text.txt` is incremented and saved? EDIT: Ok, then it's solved. GL :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to leave an answer on this for future reference for others. Please check the files included into the php file being run by the Cron have absolute paths and not just paths local to the file itself.

Ie:
do NOT have:
include 'inc/test.php';

You would need to use for example:
include '/var/www/cron/inc/test.php';